# Wait for external program to finish writing to file

Tags: python, subprocess, sox

I have a Python script that calls an external program (`sox` to be precise). Now I have to do several things with `sox`, but always have to wait until one file is done writing so I can use it as an input file in my next command.

`subprocess.wait()` doesn't work, because the execution of `sox` will be done, but the file won't be done writing.

Here is the code I have:

```
import tempfile
import shlex

file_url = '/some/file.wav'
out_file = 'some/out.wav'
tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
pad_cmd = 'sox ' + file_url + ' ' + tmp_file.name + ' pad 0.0 3.0'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(pad_cmd))
trim_cmd = 'sox ' + tmp_file.name + ' -t wav ' + out_file + ' trim 0.0 3.0'
```

Any way to wait for the file to finish writing to `tmp_file.name` without using a timer that waits for a fixed amount of time. Or is there a built-in way in `sox` to use the output file as input? The special filename `-` didn't work for `pad` and `trim`.

Comment: *"the execution of sox will be done, but the file won't be done writing."* -- if it is true (it might be if `sox` is just a launcher for another program that does the actual writing to the file e.g., if the file is opened in a tab of already existing text editor) then in that case: what you ask **can't be done** for an arbitrary subprocess, you might hack some solution specific to `sox` though. Are you absolutely sure that by the time `sox` exits the file is not done?

Comment: Can you instruct `sox` to write to stdout instead of a file e.g., `sox input.wav - pad 0.0 3.0 | sox - -t wav out.wav trim 0.0 3.0`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh, didn't know about the special filenames. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work though. I get `sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of `-'` errors for both `-` times.

Comment: Does `sox` work with a named pipe (`os.fifo()`)?

Comment: @Sennster i had a similar issue but a different language.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290316/how-to-wait-for-a-file-to-be-released-by-another-external-process  i used a timer and check if the file is available to be moved (just a rename operation) if it fails(which means the file is not ready yet for any operation) I sleep then try again.. I do this `X` times before quitting my attempts.. You can do some testing to determine optimal wait times

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm not absolutely sure, if by the time `sox` exits the file is done or not. Some tests of mine has suggested so. But I just found out that writing to `stdout` does work. You just have to specify the file type in both commands. Though `sox` has some sort of problem to create the header for the wav files, but that's not a problem in my case. The command should be `sox input.wav - -t wav pad 0.0 3.0 | sox - -t wav out.wav trim 0.0 3.0`

Comment: Oh. Little error in above command. It should be: `sox input.wav -t wav - pad 0.0 3.0 | sox -t wav - out.wav trim 0.0 3.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`sox` works with stdin/stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424704/wait-for-external-program-to-finish-writing-to-file#comment34118538_22424704):

```
#!/bin/sh
sox input.wav -t wav - pad 0.0 3.0 | sox -t wav - out.wav trim 0.0 3.0
```

then you could write it in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pad = Popen(["sox", "input.wav", "-t", "wav", "-", "pad", "0.0", "3.0"],
            stdout=PIPE)
trim = Popen(['sox', '-t', 'wav', '-', 'out.wav', 'trim', '0.0', '3.0'],
             stdin=pad.stdout)
pad.stdout.close() # notify pad on write if trim dies prematurely
pipestatus = [p.wait() for p in [pad, trim]]
```

Note: if you don't use an untrusted input to construct the commands then you could pass them as a single line for readability (the shell creates the pipe in this case):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

cmd = "sox input.wav - -t wav pad 0.0 3.0 | sox - -t wav out.wav trim 0.0 3.0"
check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

---

If you can't make it to write/read to/from stdout/stdin then you could try a named pipe, to avoid waiting for a file:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkfifo /tmp/sox.fifo
sox /tmp/sox.fifo -t wav out.wav trim 0.0 3.0 & # read from fifo
sox input.wav /tmp/sox.fifo pad 0.0 3.0         # write to fifo
```

or the same in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, check_call

with named_pipe() as path:
    trim = Popen(["sox", path, '-t', 'wav', 'out.wav', 'trim', '0.0', '3.0'])
    check_call(["sox", "input.wav", path, "pad", "0.0", "3.0"]) # pad
rc = trim.wait()
```

where `named_pipe()` is defined as:

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager
from shutil     import rmtree
from tempfile   import mkdtemp

@contextmanager
def named_pipe():
    dirname = mkdtemp()
    try:
        path = os.path.join(dirname, 'named_pipe')
        os.mkfifo(path)
        yield path
    finally:
        rmtree(dirname)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wait file before it will be avaiable for reading:

```
handle = open(tmp_file.name)
from subprocess import select
select.select([handle], [], [])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I'm not sure how I can know when the file will be available for reading? Does `select.selec([handle],[],[])` return something?

Comment: do not import `select` from `subprocess` module, use `import select` instead.

Comment: if `f = open(filename)` succeeds then `select.select([f], [], [])` may return immediately i.e., you can't use it to wait for a file.