# Python: Read data from files with sometimes are compressed and sometimes not

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I need to read binary data from some files that are normally compressed with gzip. I have managed to read the data by using the gzip module:

```
def decode(self, filename):
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        # ReadData
```

However sometimes the files are not compressed in which case I get an IOError (because the file does not have the gzip header).

I could do something like:

```
try:
    f = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    f._read_gzip_header()
    f.rewind()
except IOError:
    f.close()
    f = open(filename, 'rb')

with f as gz:
    #ReadData
```

but I don't feel it is a good way to fix it.

I am looking for an elegant solution to solve this problem. I will write several "decode" functions for several file types. The solution I consider are to create a subclass of the GzipFile to deal with it but I believe there might be better ways.

I am using Python 2.7

Thank you in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? I wouldn't close the file and then immediately reopen it, but handling a potential `IOError` with try/except is exactly right. Just try to read it as gzip except `IOError` read as plain text except `IOError` traceback. Then do all your processing cleanly, with the processing code unaware of how the file was opened.

Comment: Well, perhaps nothing is wrong with my solution (I am not so experienced in Python and sometimes I doubt what is good/wrong). The point why I did not like my solution was because I will write at least 6 decode functions (for 6 different file types) and I thought there might be a better way that I could use to avoid writing that try-except block in every function. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: If the issue is that you don't want to duplicate the code then just create a new contextmanager that yields a file-like object with uncompressed data whether input is compressed or not. Here's a [code example of a contextmanager `named_pipe()` that encapsulates creation of a named pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22435492/4279)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the first two bytes are `\x1f` and `\x8b`, as per [RFC 1952](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer):

> Member header and trailer
>
> ID1 (IDentification 1) ID2 (IDentification 2)
>       These have the fixed values ID1 = 31 (0x1f, \037), ID2 = 139 (0x8b, \213), to identify the file as being in gzip format.

So for example,

```
with open('test.gz','rb') as f:
    print(f.read(2))

b'\x1f\x8b' #well, that was gzipped

with open('test','rb') as f:
    print(f.read(2))

b'he' #must not be gzipped
```

Presumably you would do some control flow based on those two bytes, then `f.seek(0)` and proceed accordingly.

But honestly?  Your solution is fine (modulo the unnecessary close/reopen part).  `try/except` is pythonic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (My comment to Two-Bit Alchemist applies also here). But I did not understand which part of my code was unnecessary: Don't I need to use close() if I don't use the "with" statement to open the file?

Comment: Yes, you should try to manually explicitly close file objects if not using the with statement as a context manager. However, writing `f.close` then `open(same_file)` back to back is as pointless as closing then re-opening a door you're about to exit through. :P